# Java 8, anonymous recursive nested method

Tags: java, recursion, lambda, functional-programming

My goal is to migrate the method getAllFields into init by re writing it as an anonymous function, I know it's quite possible using functional programming.

```
public void init(){

}

public static Field[] getAllFields(Class klass) {
    List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<Field>();
    fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(klass.getDeclaredFields()));
    if (klass.getSuperclass() != null) {
        fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(getAllFields(klass.getSuperclass())));
    }
    return fields.toArray(new Field[] {});
}
```

I've tried using Function and also BiFunction but got lost abit.
Can any one give a snippet for how to implement such case?

Comment: What's the goal? Obfuscate your code? There are plenty of cases where using lambdas is useful, but this is really not one of them.

Comment: Please show what you've tried and explain what problems you're facing.

Comment: I disagree, I think that once your whole code logic is encapsulated inside 1 method, it's much more maintainable

Comment: Err, that's what you have now: everything is encapsulated inside getAllFields. This method does one thing, correctly. It obeys the single responsibility principle, and has a name indicating what it does. What's the problem?

Comment: In C# your'e able using the Func delegate to create a nested anonymous recursive method, was wondering how can you do such thing in java 8

Comment: You can create a method reference pointing to the above method: `Function<Class<?>, Field[]> f = MyClass::getAllFields;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `getAllFields` implementation is horribly inefficient, creating multiple `ArrayList` instances and arrays, repeatedly copying the entire data between them back and forth. Thankfully, class hierarchies rarely are that deep that this becomes a bottleneck.

Still, you can implement this with a straight-forward loop, which is simpler and more efficient:

```
public static Field[] getAllFields(Class<?> klass) {
    List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<>();
    for(; klass!=null; klass=klass.getSuperclass())
        Collections.addAll(fields, klass.getDeclaredFields());
    return fields.toArray(new Field[0]);
}
```

There is not the slightest benefit from using recursion here.

With a loop, you can easily create a `Function` if you really wish:

```
public void init(){
    Function<Class<?>,Field[]> f = klass -> {
        List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<>();
        for(; klass!=null; klass=klass.getSuperclass())
            Collections.addAll(fields, klass.getDeclaredFields());
        return fields.toArray(new Field[0]);
    };
    Field[] someFields = f.apply(SomeClass.class);
}
```

Though, of course, there isn’t even a reason to put the loop into a `Function` at all. You only wanted to have a function here due to your wish to use that inefficient *recursive* implementation, but lambda expressions don’t support accessing themself at all. They only can access the *field* to which the instance implementing the functional interface got stored, *if* it was stored in a field, which you don’t want. With a local lambda expression, recursion is impossible.

With the straight-forward loop, you can just write

```
public void init(){
    List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Class<?> klass=SomeClass.class; klass!=null; klass=klass.getSuperclass())
        Collections.addAll(fields, klass.getDeclaredFields());
    Field[] someFields = fields.toArray(new Field[0]);
}
```

though, actually, there is rarely a real reason for copying the contents of `fields` into an array, you could just work with the `List<Field>` instead.

That said, encapsulating the loop into a named method describing its purpose, like `getAllFields`, is actually a good thing. If you don’t want to expose it, declare it `private` instead of `public`.

Comment: The inductive or recursive approach for this matter wasn't the topic even though of course you're extremely right about gaining nothing with going with the recursive approach & I completely accept the fact that the inductive way is far more justified than the rec 1, I was more concerned about the functional programming methodology just like in javaScript,  which allows to create an anonymous method that will not create a reference nor will create a method reference, will just retrieve a value to a local method reference, was hoping to see this in java 8.

Comment: A lambda expression is like an anonymous method (in fact, they are compiled to a method), but it can’t call itself recursively. Well, the method invocation syntax requires a method name…

Answer (score 2):

This is not (yet) directly possible. In Java 9, the `Stream` class will have an [`iterate`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate-T-java.util.function.Predicate-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-) method, which allows to implement this as follows:

```
Field[] allFields = Stream
    .iterate((klass, Objects::nonNull, Class::getSuperclass)
    .flatMap(c -> Stream.of(c.getDeclaredFields()))
    .toArray(Field[]::new);
```

However, the `getAllFields` method that you already have is a nice, clean implementation of the desired functionality, and the name makes unambiguously clear *what this method does*. The functional implementation would be far more difficult to understand.